SQLAlchemy filter on Query again got extra junk rows
I have Django experience. Now I would like to try some DIY python packages to my mini project. I Here is my code.
models.py
import enum
from datetime import date, datetime

from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


class StatusEnum(enum.Enum):
    """Enum class of status field."""
    pending = "pending"
    in_progress = "in_progress"
    completed = "completed"


class TaskContent(SQLModel, table=True):
    """Model class for TaskContent history."""
    identifier: str = Field(primary_key=True)   # For redo mechanism
    id: int = Field(primary_key=False)  # For human use
    title: str = Field(nullable=True)
    description: str = Field(nullable=True)
    due_date: date = Field(default=None, nullable=True)
    status: StatusEnum = Field(default=StatusEnum.pending)
    is_deleted: bool = Field(default=False)  # For redo mechanism
    created_by: int = Field(nullable=True, default=None, foreign_key="user.id")
    created_at: datetime = Field(default=datetime.now())  # For redo mechanism


class CurrentTaskContent(SQLModel, table=True):
    """Model class for current."""
    # https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/114
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("identifier", "id"), )

    identifier: str = Field(primary_key=True)   # For redo mechanism
    id: int = Field(primary_key=False)  # For human use
    created_by: int = Field(nullable=True, default=None, foreign_key="user.id")
    updated_by: int = Field(nullable=True, default=None, foreign_key="user.id")
    created_at: datetime = Field(default=datetime.now())
    updated_at: datetime = Field(default=datetime.now())


class User(SQLModel, table=True):
    """User model of this application."""
    id: int = Field(primary_key=True)
    username: str = Field(nullable=False)


main.py
def get_queryset() -> sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query:
    """Get the queryset of tasks."""
    with (Session(engine) as session):
        # List out available id.
        available_id_list = session.query(CurrentTaskContent).all()
        available_identifier_list = [i.identifier for i in available_id_list]

        # Get task and id
        queryset_tasks = session.query(TaskContent).filter(
            TaskContent.identifier.in_(available_identifier_list)
        ).subquery()

        # Get username and id
        username_query = session.query(User.username, User.id).subquery()

        # Join the queryset and username
        final_query = session.query(queryset_tasks, username_query).outerjoin(
            username_query, and_(queryset_tasks.c.created_by == username_query.c.id)
        )
        return final_query


The tasks_queryset.count() is 5 which is correct. My database has only 5 rows.
Then I try to filter again by due_date with the following.
Problem:
aa and bb both of them shows me 25 which is not what I need.
aa = tasks_queryset.filter(tasks_queryset.subquery().c.due_date == due_date_instance)
bb = tasks_queryset.filter(TaskContent.due_date == due_date_instance)

Workaround Solution:
Put due_date to the table query.
        queryset_tasks = session.query(TaskContent).filter(
            TaskContent.identifier.in_(available_identifier_list),
            or_(TaskContent.due_date == _due_date, _due_date is None)
        ).subquery()

Question:
How to filter the tasks_queryset with given due_date?

If I've followed your query correctly you should be able to simplify that down using joins and avoids having subqueries.
with Session(engine) as session:
    final_query = session.query(TaskContent, User.username)\
        .join(
            User, TaskContent.created_by == User.id
        )\
        .join(
            CurrentTaskContent, CurrentTaskContent.identifier == TaskContent.identifier
        )\
        .filter(
            (CurrentTaskContent.identifier != None),
            or_(TaskContent.due_date == _due_date, _due_date is None)
        )
    return final_query


Thank you for your reply. Is SQLAlchemy alway start query with table?
Can I get query from task_queryset and the .filter() like Django.

Not familiar enough with Django to know what you're trying to compare sorry. It was just my thought looking at what your end result was trying to achieve that you'd being able to write a single SQLAlchemy query.  If you do a print on your task_queryset before and after you apply your filter you'll be able to see the raw SQL and what changes are being made.
